# Adding Library snowflake-snowpark-python to Azure Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-functions, snowpark

Hi All I am new to Azure Function , this is my case ,i have Snowflake Snowpark library which is python 3.8 compatible and my Azure function python version is 3.9.7. When i am trying to run this code using visual studio  (Virtual env selected as 3.9.7 ) , Snowflake Snowpark library import statement doesn't get recognized , I mean it shows red line and when i hover it, red line it says python library not available.
My question is , is it possible to add external library of python 3.8 version into 3.9
python virtual env. If yes how do i do this.

Despite this error if i try to upload my code into Azure function from Visual Studio ; the deployment fails with error " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement snowflake-snowpark-python"

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake connectors have been behind in python versions in almost all the use cases I have used.

Documentation states The Snowpark API requires Python 3.8 ([Snowpark API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/setup.html#prerequisites))

Most likely just need to update venv to 3.8.x